# Issue comparing duplicated files on Google Drive with GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I expected the GAS below to delete files with the same name inside a given folder. The loop inside another loop should compare all files with all files, but it does not.

Since there are 5 files in the folder, the script should make 5x5 comparisons, but it makes only 5. Where is my fault?

code:

```
function setTrashedDuplicatedFiles(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1FfbNvPQpg6Ilx-5VLuSIePvpl-FxewFl");
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var files_ = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext())
  { 
    var file = files.next()
    while (files_.hasNext())
    {
      var file_ = files_.next()
      Logger.log("file: " + file + " = " + "file_: " + file_)
      Logger.log("file.getId(): " + file.getId() + " = " + "file_.getId(): " + file_.getId())
      if((file === file_) && (file.getId() != file_.getId()))
      {
        file.setTrashed(true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current output:

```
file: File1.pdf = file_: File1.pdf
file.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA = file_.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA
file: File1.pdf = file_: File2.pdf
file.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA = file_.getId(): 1LY68d1aP9DLe5LqkzZyCJVdQIAm9XzzY
file: File1.pdf = file_: File2.pdf
file.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA = file_.getId(): 19tKdBNt5bzxAOfcO1n14a_DbjWLb-LN-
file: File1.pdf = file_: File1.pdf
file.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA = file_.getId(): 1Quwyi6WIP0dt3qgV4S5XJof1wMu9mRP1
file: File1.pdf = file_: File1.pdf
file.getId(): 1yyFlRAGISjKstVxPRu8Eqi4iCIYJGDZA = file_.getId(): 1fjMu1NEJu9ZI3aFhYpFyLkw_o79KiTQa
```

Comment: In  addition,  `file === file_` will not work.  Different objects are never equal. `toString()` might work, but  even if something like the filename is different, it's possible that that those strings are different as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to move the file to the trash box when the filename is duplicated.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the file object is compared instead of the filename like `file === file_`. In this case, the if statement is always `false`. In order to compare the filename, please use `(file.getName() === file_.getName())`. This has already been mentioned by [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285168/issue-comparing-duplicated-files-on-google-drive-with-gas#comment108417351_61285168).
- `getFiles()` returns the FileIterator. In this case, your 2nd while loop is only one loop. By this, your script cannot remove the files of duplicated filename. So I would like to propose the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

As other pattern, how about the following script? In this case, one loop is used. So the process cost can be reduced than that of above modified script.

```
function setTrashedDuplicatedFiles(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1FfbNvPQpg6Ilx-5VLuSIePvpl-FxewFl");
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  let fileObj = {};
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const filename = file.getName();
    if (filename in fileObj) {
      file.setTrashed(true);
    } else {
      fileObj[filename] = file;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles)

Comment: Modified script won't work, I think. For `file#1`, ``file_#1`` to ``file_#5 ``will be looped. But for `file#2`, there won't be remaining `files_` to loop(`files_.hasNext()` will be false for second outer loop `file` loop)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I noticed the modification point of my answer. So I updated it. Could you please confirm it? As the result, I proposed only the sample script. In order to use the OP's script, for example, when the filenames are `File1.pdf`, `File1.pdf`, `File1.pdf`, `File1.pdf`, `File2.pdf`, I think that it will work. Because in this case, the work can be done with only one loop.

Comment: Thank so much again guys. That works perfectly. Nice logic.

Comment: I just wanted to highlight to other users who my want to use this code that you may need to enable the new V8 runtime for Apps Script in order to use `let` declaration: Go to GAS editor, then 'Run' menu and finally click on **"Enable new App Script runtime powered by Chrome V8"**, now you are all set.

Comment: @Cleber Marques Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.